# Why is entropy not a thermodynamic potential in the sense of Legendre transform?

Tags: thermodynamics, canonical-conjugation

We can formulate thermodynamic theory using entropy S as state function or equivalently using the internal energy U, and U is related with all other thermodynamic potentials via the Legendre transform, and these potentials can also be the state function that represents all possible states of equilibrium of the system.
Also in mechanics the Hamiltonian function is too the Legendre transform of the Lagrangian, and we say that the two formulations are equivalent in the sense that they can equally explain the dynamics of the system. 
So, why is it that S is not a thermodynamic potential? if it is a possible representation of the state function.
Couldn't we define $\dfrac{1}{T}$ and $-\dfrac{P}{T}$ as the conjugate variable of U and V respectively (just as an example)??

Comment: Taking the fundamental relation as $S=S(U,V)$ and eliminating $U$ in favour of $1/T$ and/or $V$ in favour of $P/T$ by Legendre transformations gives a set of potentials called Massieu functions. See section 5-4 of "Thermodynamics and an introduction to Thermostatistics" by Herbert B. Callen.

Comment: It's certainly a done thing to take $S = S(E,V,N)$ as a "master function" and its full differential as a "master equation". No problem there. But I wouldn't call it a "thermodynamic potential" because it doesn't have dimensions of energy.